# How can i create a 45 degrees turned rectangle in css?

Tags: html, css, less

How can i create a 45 degrees turned rectangle in css? I have no clue where to start...

[image: Example]

Comment: Take a look at CSS transforms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: Start by [rotating it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate).

Comment: Why didn't you want make this section through background-image? otherwise use transform: rotate(-45deg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CSS Transform` to accomplish this. See the example code below:

```css
div.examplediv {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

p.exampletext {
    /* Rotate p back so that only div is rotated. */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="examplediv">
   <p class="exampletext">
      Hello
   </p>
</div>
```

For more information check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Hope this helps!